# Nutch + Solr - Indexer causes java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: java, tomcat, hadoop, solr, nutch

I have configured my 2 servers to run in distributed mode (with Hadoop) and my configuration for crawling process is Nutch 2.2.1 - HBase (as a storage) and Solr. Solr is run by Tomcat. The problem is everytime I try to do the last step - I mean when I want to index data from HBase into Solr. After then this **[1]** error occures. I tried to add CATALINA_OPTS (or JAVA_OPTS) like this:

> CATALINA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -Xms1g -Xmx6000m
>   -XX:MinHeapFreeRatio=10 -XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=30 -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled"

to Tomcat's catalina.sh script and run server with this script but it didn't help. I also add these **[2]** properties to nutch-site.xml file but it ended up with `OutOfMemory` again. Can you help me please?

**[1]**

```
2014-09-06 22:52:50,683 FATAL org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child: Error running child : java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space 
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2367) 
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.expandCapacity(AbstractStringBuilder.java:130) 
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.ensureCapacityInternal(AbstractStringBuilder.java:114) 
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:587) 
    at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:332) 
    at java.io.StringWriter.write(StringWriter.java:77) 
    at org.apache.solr.common.util.XML.escape(XML.java:204) 
    at org.apache.solr.common.util.XML.escapeCharData(XML.java:77) 
    at org.apache.solr.common.util.XML.writeXML(XML.java:147) 
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.util.ClientUtils.writeVal(ClientUtils.java:161) 
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.util.ClientUtils.writeXML(ClientUtils.java:129) 
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.UpdateRequest.writeXML(UpdateRequest.java:355) 
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.UpdateRequest.getXML(UpdateRequest.java:271) 
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.RequestWriter.getContentStream(RequestWriter.java:66) 
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.RequestWriter$LazyContentStream.getDelegate(RequestWriter.java:94) 
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.RequestWriter$LazyContentStream.getName(RequestWriter.java:104) 
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer.request(HttpSolrServer.java:247) 
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer.request(HttpSolrServer.java:197) 
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.AbstractUpdateRequest.process(AbstractUpdateRequest.java:117) 
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServer.add(SolrServer.java:68) 
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServer.add(SolrServer.java:54) 
    at org.apache.nutch.indexwriter.solr.SolrIndexWriter.close(SolrIndexWriter.java:96) 
    at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexWriters.close(IndexWriters.java:117) 
    at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexerOutputFormat$1.close(IndexerOutputFormat.java:54) 
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewDirectOutputCollector.close(MapTask.java:650) 
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.closeQuietly(MapTask.java:1793) 
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:779) 
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:364) 
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255) 
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) 
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415) 
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1190)
```

**[2]**

```
<property>
  <name>http.content.limit</name>
  <value>150000000</value>
</property>

<property>
   <name>indexer.max.tokens</name>
   <value>100000</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>http.timeout</name>
  <value>50000</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>solr.commit.size</name>
  <value>100</value>
</property>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it with configuration below (mapred-site.xml file):

```
<property>
  <name>mapred.jobtracker.retirejob.interval</name>
  <value>3600000</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>mapred.job.tracker.retiredjobs.cache.size</name>
  <value>100</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>mapred.child.java.opts</name>
<value>-Xmx4000m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>mapred.child.ulimit</name>
<value>6000000</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>mapred.jobtracker.completeuserjobs.maximum</name>
  <value>5</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>mapred.job.tracker.handler.count</name>
  <value>5</value>
</property>
```